# Custom CALayer Animation View - unable to animate

Tags: swift, animation, calayer

I'm working on a custom view made up of CALayers and I'm unable to animate it.

[image]

My application is a check out flow.  Each screen is an item in the checkout cart.  As the user is moving through the cart up to the invoice a new controller is pushed onto the stack.  I use my progress view to update the user on where there are in the cart.

I am able to update the progress view, however I am unable to get it to animate.  The progress view is recreated on each new view controller and filled to the specified amount.

```
//creates the shape layer, grayed with spaces in between
func createShapeLayer(_ count: Int) {

    //calculate width of the view
    let width = self.frame.width

    //divide by the number of items(count) = single progress length
    let singleProgressLength = width/CGFloat(count)


    // take 10% off that as the gap length
    let gapLength = singleProgressLength * 0.10

    //new single progress length = progress length - gap
    var newSingleProgressLength : CGFloat = 0.0
    let staticWidth = singleProgressLength - gapLength

    //loop through the count
    for i in 1...count {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()

        //start at 0 for the first layer
        layer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0 + (newSingleProgressLength + gapLength), y: 0, width: staticWidth, height: self.frame.height), cornerRadius: 1).cgPath
        newSingleProgressLength += (staticWidth + gapLength)
        if i <= coloredUpToIndex {
            layer.fillColor = UIColor(netHex:0xF7B445).cgColor

        }else {
            layer.fillColor = UIColor(netHex:0xD8D8D8).cgColor
        }
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        layerArray.append(layer)
    }


}


// Adds increment to the progress view, filling a rectangle with animation
func animateViewUpdate() {
    var delay : TimeInterval = 0.5
    for layer in layerArray {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) { () -> Void in
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
            animation.duration = 1.0
            animation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: 0.0 as Float)
            animation.toValue = NSNumber(value: 1.0 as Float)
            layer.add(animation, forKey: "animateOpacity")
            self.perform(#selector(ECProgressView.animateViewUpdate), with: nil, afterDelay: delay)
        }
        delay += 0.5
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try animate the stroke it self?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  That led me to find this post and I think I am closer. Able to get a layer on screen animating consistently. http://jamesonquave.com/blog/fun-with-cashapelayer/

Comment: glad i helped! :)